# How do I use a wild card in the middle of an sql server like query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

When doing a select in SQL Server i can put a % at the start or end of the queries text to indicate I want any number of characters of other text, but im not sure how to do it in the middle.

e.g. I want SQL like below,

```
select *
From Table
Where name like '%[Error] Something failed in (%) session%'
```

That when ran against the below data

```
Row | Date      | Log Message
1   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'
2   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Ilenes) session'
3   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'; Some other warning
4   |2016-01-01 |'[Warning] Something else went wrong'
5   |2016-01-01 |'[Warning] Some other warning'
```

Would give me

```
Row |Date       | Log Message
1   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'
2   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Ilenes) session'
3   |2016-01-01 |'[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'; Some other warning
```

But instead it gives nothing back, what do i need to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is due the presence of `[]` in string. `[]` is used with `LIKE` operator to find

> any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set
>   ([abcdef]).

so you need to `ESCAPE` the *square bracket's*

```
select 1 
where '[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'
like '%\[Error] Something failed in (%) session%' escape '\'
```

or

```
select 1 
where '[Error] Something failed in (Freds) session'
like '%[[]Error] Something failed in (%) session%'
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/5048)